# python @memoize vs functools.lru_cache

Tags: python

I'm not sure what the advantages and disadvantages of these 2 are. Provided `@lru_cache` from functools is a standard library tool and seems to have more control over `@memoize`, why does `@memoize` even exist?

Edit: I am referring to memoize from here -> https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

Comment: Are you looking for an answer other than "Because someone has put that `@memoized` implementation on that wiki page an nobody has deleted it from there yet."?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`functools.lru_cache` was added in python 3.2. For those using python 2, and for libraries written to work with it (e.g. all major libs) it cannot be used.

The workaround is to use the [`@memoize`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) recipe from the decorator library.

If you only use python 3, there is basically no reason not to use `lru_cache`.

Comment: How do I get for example all keys or all values stored in `lru_cache`? That's something I actually wanted recently.

Comment: `lru_cache` _can_ be used in 2.7 with [functools32](https://pypi.org/project/functools32/)

Comment: `@memoize recipe from the decorator library` - can you share a link, please?

Comment: Edited with a link.